# how to add to an array of struct pointer

Tags: c, operating-system

I create an array of struct Thread_Queue call queueUsed and every time enqueue_thread function(thread, queue) is called, i check if queueUsed contain that queue, if not, add that queue to thread. what am i doing wrong?

this is part of my kthrad.h file and enqueue_thread is used in my kthread.c file

```
extern struct Thread_Queue *queueUsed[100]; 

static __inline__ void Enqueue_Thread(struct Thread_Queue *queue,
                                      struct Kernel_Thread *kthread) {
    Add_To_Back_Of_Thread_Queue(queue, kthread);

    int x=0;
    for(;x<100;x++){

        if(queueUsed[x] == NULL){
            queueUsed[x]=queue;
            break;
        }else if(queueUsed[x] == queue)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding **pointers to queues** to a thread instead of messages to the queue of a thread? And also: is there any locking around the call to this function to ensure that `if(queueUsed[x] == NULL){ queueUsed[x]=queue;` is not a race-condition?

Comment: i havent used c in 2 years so I have no idea if im doing this right or not? i didnt even allocated any space for queueUsed, that is ok right?

Comment: Actually, @help, you _did_ allocate space for `queueUsed`; at least you did if your program links correctly.  You just allocated it in your program’s data segment rather than on the heap.

Comment: I like: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dan/class/165/notes/memory.html and http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html